# FileReader() fails to read large files

Tags: jquery, google-apps-script, google-drive-api, filereader

I'm trying to upload file to Google Drive using this app script, it works on smaller files but fails when uploading files larger than approx 1 GB +

As soon as i load the large file, the onerror function gets executed. I couldn't figure out of making file read in slice.
Here is my code. Any help will be appreciated.

```
const chunkSize = 5242880;
$('#uploadfile').on("change", function() {
    var file = this.files[0];
    if (file.name != "") {
        var fr = new FileReader();
        fr.fileName = file.name;
        fr.fileSize = file.size;
        fr.fileType = file.type;
        fr.onload = init;
        fr.readAsArrayBuffer(file);
    }
});
function init() {
    $("#progress").text("Initializing.");
    var fileName = this.fileName;
    var fileSize = this.fileSize;
    var fileType = this.fileType;
    console.log({fileName: fileName, fileSize: fileSize, fileType: fileType});
    var buf = this.result;
    var chunkpot = getChunkpot(chunkSize, fileSize);
    var uint8Array = new Uint8Array(buf);
    var chunks = chunkpot.chunks.map(function(e) {
        return {
            data: uint8Array.slice(e.startByte, e.endByte + 1),
            length: e.numByte,
            range: "bytes " + e.startByte + "-" + e.endByte + "/" + chunkpot.total,
        };
    });
    google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(function(at) {
        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.open("POST", "https://www.googleapis.com/upload/drive/v3/files?uploadType=resumable");
        xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization', "Bearer " + at);
        xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', "application/json");
        xhr.send(JSON.stringify({
            mimeType: fileType,
            name: fileName,
        }));
        xhr.onload = function() {
            doUpload({
                location: xhr.getResponseHeader("location"),
                chunks: chunks,
            });
        };
        xhr.onerror = function() {
            console.log(xhr.response);
        };
    }).getAt();
}
function doUpload(e) {
    var chunks = e.chunks;
    var location = e.location;
    var cnt = 0;
    var end = chunks.length;
    var temp = function callback(cnt) {
        var e = chunks[cnt];
        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.open("PUT", location, true);
        xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Range', e.range);
        xhr.send(e.data);
        xhr.onloadend = function() {
            var status = xhr.status;
            cnt += 1;
            console.log("Uploading: " + status + " (" + cnt + " / " + end + ")");
            $("#progress").text("Uploading: " + Math.floor(100 * cnt / end) + "%");
            if (status == 308) {
                callback(cnt);
            } else if (status == 200) {
                $("#progress").text("Done.");
            } else {
                $("#progress").text("Error: " + xhr.response);
            }
        };
    }(cnt);
}
function getChunkpot(chunkSize, fileSize) {
    var chunkPot = {};
    chunkPot.total = fileSize;
    chunkPot.chunks = [];
    if (fileSize > chunkSize) {
        var numE = chunkSize;
        var endS = function(f, n) {
            var c = f % n;
            if (c == 0) {
                return 0;
            } else {
                return c;
            }
        }(fileSize, numE);
        var repeat = Math.floor(fileSize / numE);
        for (var i = 0; i <= repeat; i++) {
            var startAddress = i * numE;
            var c = {};
            c.startByte = startAddress;
            if (i < repeat) {
                c.endByte = startAddress + numE - 1;
                c.numByte = numE;
                chunkPot.chunks.push(c);
            } else if (i == repeat && endS > 0) {
                c.endByte = startAddress + endS - 1;
                c.numByte = endS;
                chunkPot.chunks.push(c);
            }
        }
    } else {
        var chunk = {
            startByte: 0,
            endByte: fileSize - 1,
            numByte: fileSize,
        };
        chunkPot.chunks.push(chunk);
    }
    return chunkPot;
}
```

Comment: There is a `slice()` method on the Blob interface that these Files inherit. Though I'm not too cler as to why exactly you need to read it? Can't you just send the Files as is?

Comment: without including fr.readAsArrayBuffer(file); upload doesn't work.

Comment: If this is working, why don't you want to use it?

Comment: its not working for large files..working for small files only.

Comment: The request should be the same if you pass a Blob/File or an ArrayBuffer, so I don't see why it would fail with a File, except of course if you didn't do it correctly.

Answer (score 1):

It is failing for big files as you are reading the whole file in memory before processing it.

A `File` object is an instance of `Blob` which has `.slice` method to create a small-small view of the file.

You can just call the `readAsArrayBuffer` function for smaller file slices.

For ex. you need to write one function in which you will be using some chunk size

```
var chunk = 1024;
var offset = 0;
var fr = new FileReader();
fr.onload = function() {
        var view = new Uint8Array(fr.result);
        for (var i = 0; i < view.length; ++i) {
            if (view[i] === 10 || view[i] === 13) {
                // Check if \r or \n found
                // column length = offset + position of \r or \n
                callback(offset + i);
                return;
            }
        }
        // continue reading slices if \r or \n not found.
        offset += chunk;
        continue_reading();
    };
    fr.onerror = function() {
        // Something went wrong
        callback(0);
    };
    continue_reading();

    function continue_reading() {
        if (offset >= file.size) {
            // If no \r or \n found. The column size is equal to the full
            // file size
            callback(file.size);
            return;
        }
        var slice = file.slice(offset, offset + chunk);
        fr.readAsArrayBuffer(slice);
    }
```

Please note that these clarifications are made with an assumption that the input is ASCII.

Comment: I can not put your answer in my context. Can you please help me with that. thanks

Comment: So, tell me what is the issue you are facing.

Comment: I can not call readAsArrayBuffer function on onload (int) as file upload wont execute without doing readAsArrayBuffer() on onChange function

Comment: So the problem with you is when to call "function init()" function to upload the file?